# Unable to make an element rotate into another

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to make some simple HTML-CSS sprite while adding some animation. The problem (on top of centring the whole and making it responsive) is this that the `inner-inner-circle` should rotate inside the `inner-circle` but it gets outside. I'm still trying to figure out this tools (HTML and CSS) so, can anyone help me to fix this problem?

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            *{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .outer-circle{
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 600px;
                height: 600px;
                background-color: green;
                border-radius: 360px;
                z-index: 0;
            }
            .inner-circle{
                position: relative;
                top: 30px;
                z-index: 3;
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                background-color: yellow;
                border-radius: 180px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            .inner-inner-circle{
                position: relative;
                z-index: 4;
                width: 150px;
                height: 150px;
                background-color: black;
                border-radius: 90px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                top: 150px;
                left: 1%;
                animation: changebg 5s linear 2s infinite alternate;
            }
            .halph-moon{
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1;
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
                border-radius: 300px;
                background-color: black;
                top: 50px;
                left: 710px;
            }
            .cover{
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 2;
                width: 420px; 
                height: 420px; 
                border-radius: 252px;
                background-color: green;
                top: 15px;
                left: 750px;
            }
        

            @keyframes changebg{
                0%{
                    background-color: black;
                    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
                }
                100%{
                    background-color: red;
                    transform: rotate(360deg) translateY(100%) rotate(360deg);
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer-circle">
            <div class="cover"></div>
            <div class="halph-moon"></div>
            <div class="inner-circle">
                <div class="inner-inner-circle"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

changes to your css

```
inner-inner-circle {
  top: 75px; - // half of the original height;
}
```

inside changebg animation make changes to 100%

```
   100%{
        transform: rotate(360deg) translateY(50%) rotate(360deg);
     }
```

I think first you need to align the inner-inner-circle to center and then translateY to 50% only so that it will be inside of inner-circle. so that animation will be inside of the inner-circle

Comment: It works, the `inner-inner-circle` stays inside the `inner-circle`. But why does the rotation follows a spiral path instead of hovering the circumference of `inner-circle`?